# How to update (replace, not add) the only row in a Listview in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, task, real-time

I have a continuous stream of data frames which I am populating as a row in a WPF listview. When the next frame arrives I want to replace the existing one in the listview and display it in the real time. How can I achieve that? Below is the XAML of the listview :

```
<ListView x:Name="lstNames" Margin="5,5,294,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView x:Name="grdNames">
                                <GridViewColumn Header="D2"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding D2}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="D3"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding D3}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="D1"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding D1}"/>

                                <GridViewColumn Header="Z2"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Z2}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Z3"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Z3}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Z1"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Z1}"/>

                                <GridViewColumn Header="M2"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding M2}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="M3"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding M3}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="M1"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding M1}"/>

                                <GridViewColumn Header="R2"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding M2}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="R3"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding M3}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="R1"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding M1}"/>


                                <GridViewColumn Header="K2"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding K2}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="K3"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding K3}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="K1"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding K1}"/>







                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
```

The implementation here :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
private ObservableCollection<sensor_id> p_sensors;
 public class sensor_id 
        {
            public int D2 { get; set; }
            public int D3 { get; set; }

            public int D1 { get; set; }

            public int Z2 { get; set; }
            public int Z3 { get; set; }

            public int Z1 { get; set; }

            public int M2 { get; set; }
            public int M3 { get; set; }

            public int M1 { get; set; }

            public int R2 { get; set; }
            public int R3 { get; set; }

            public int R1 { get; set; }

            public int K2 { get; set; }
            public int K3 { get; set; }

            public int K1 { get; set; }



        }

private void start_data_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            int i = 0;
            while (true && i < 10000)
            {
                p_sensors = new ObservableCollection<sensor_id> { };

                lstNames.ItemsSource = p_sensors;

                preesure_array = BLE_Connection.device_right.pressure_sensor_arr;

                test_left = BLE_Connection.device_right.frame;
                p_sensors.Add(new sensor_id()
                {
                    D2 = preesure_array[0],
                    D3 = preesure_array[1],
                    D1 = preesure_array[2],
                    Z2 = preesure_array[3],
                    Z3 = preesure_array[4],
                    Z1 = preesure_array[5],
                    M2 = preesure_array[6],
                    M3 = preesure_array[7],
                    M1 = preesure_array[8],
                    R2 = preesure_array[9],
                    R3 = preesure_array[10],
                    R1 = preesure_array[11],
                    K2 = preesure_array[12],
                    K3 = preesure_array[13],
                    K1 = preesure_array[14],
                   
            }) ;


                //Console.WriteLine("{0}:left: ", BLE_Connection.device_left.frame);

                i++;
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Completed Run");

        }


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

         }
```

What comes up as a result is that, only after the while loop completes, the listview displays all the frames as rows one after another. But I want to see exactly one row at a time and also in a real-time. I could not find any replacement of the Add function of the listview which would just update the row. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can access ObservableCollection by index. So, find index number of item to be replaced and set new item at that index.

Comment: I don't think your idea of "real-time" in wpf ui is correct. What makes you think it is not displayed "immediately"? Adding 10k rows with 15 (presumably) simple type fields would probably take 10ms on an average PC..

Comment: I think its works: replace "lstNames.ItemsSource = p_sensors;" with "lstNames.ItemsSource = null; lstNames.ItemsSource = p_sensors;"